# Graphical less alternative (log file viewer)

Tags: linux, less

While I'm comfortable in the command line, I find a GUI easier to navigate and able to fit/scroll more information at a time.

In the Windows world I'm used to TotalCommander, which has a really nice integrated viewer that works with arbitrarily large file sizes. It doesn't do "less", but presssing F2 is easy.

I don't know what the equivalent SL/RedHat (Gnome) program would be. I mostly use gEdit but it's a dog on large files. Something that opens 1GB files really fast, is able to search forwards and backwards and select large amounts of text.

Comment: less is a pager/viewer, Gedit edits... did you search your distro's repos for "text viewer" and "text editor"? There's a lot, try them out

Answer (score 1):

I think if your comfortable with the command line, maybe you would like Midnight Commander (sudo yum search mc) 
[Midnight commander google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=midnight+commander&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

While not a GUI ( more of a TUI ), Ive found it to be extremely powerful in terms of whats capable, its very quickly at loading large files, fully featured ( similar to TotalCommander ) and quite intuitive, the numbered shortcuts at the bottom are for the F- Function Keys. I especially like Ctrl+o will take you back to your shell prompt, and from there ctrl+o will take you back to mc. Very useful.

Similarly, Krusader is very popular (GUI) and fully featured also. [Krusader Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=krusader%20linux)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use mc a lot, but I would like something graphical.